# Delphi TMemo Blocking Mode?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a huge String to add to a Memo in Delphi7.
The String is about 1MB large and has many (Unicode) Characters.
My Graphic Card is not the best (Intel GMA 500).
I add the text with:

```
Memo1.Lines.Append(MyString);
```

However it looks like that the Procedure is faster than the drawing to my Memo.
Is there a way how to code this in a "blocking mode" - which means the procedure ends when all the characters are drawn?

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
I also used:

```
Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
Memo1.Lines.Append(MyString);
Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
```

Comment: If you just need to display the text, you might be able to use TListView, which can be used in "virtual" mode.

Comment: I'm nearly positive that I don't understand, but in the slim chance that I do,.. no! Adding text and drawing the window contents are different procedures. At some point in time the memo has to be updated *after* the text has been added. Whatever you block, the update speed won't be affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding your text, call `Memo1.Update`. That won't return until the memo has updated its display — it forces the memo to paint itself.